# Constructor can not be instantiated Slick Scala

Tags: sql, scala, case, slick

I was trying to convert a query from SQL into Scala code with Slick, but I have got a compiler error in filter clause: ***constructor cannot be instantiated to expected type***.

My code in Slick:

```
val subquery = (for {
      pit <- PassInTripTable.table
      t <- TripTable.table if pit.tripNoFk === t.tripNo
    } yield (pit, t))
        .map{ case (pit, t) => ( pit, Case.If(t.townFrom <= t.townTo).Then(t.townFrom ++ t.townTo).Else(t.townFrom ++ t.townTo) )}
          .groupBy(_._1.idPsgFk)
            .filter{ case ((pit, count), group) => ( group.map(_._2).countDistinct === 1)}
                .map(_._1)
    val query = PassengerTable.table.filter(_.idPsg in subquery).map(_.name)
    db.run(query.result)
```

The query in SQL itself:

```
select name from passenger
        where id_psg in
        (
          select id_psg from trip t,pass_in_trip pit
          where t.trip_no=pit.trip_no
          group by id_psg
          having count(distinct case when town_from<=town_to then town_from+town_to else town_to+town_from end)=1
        )
```

I would be very grateful if someone helped me to find an error.

Answer (score 1):

From looking at your code, it looks like the type you are matching on is not supposed to be "((pit, count), group)".

groupBy in Slick only returns a collection of Tuple2s.

http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.0.0/queries.html

So, the filter might look something like...

```
.filter{ case (pit, count) => ( count.map(_._2).countDistinct === 1)}
```

Comment: Thanks for an advice. But with such filter I get such exception: _SlickTreeException: Cannot convert node to SQL Comprehension_

Comment: Oh I didn't mean to give a syntactically correct answer.  I just was shedding light on that in your case expression, you are looking for Tuple2[Tuple2[A,B],C] and in the website it is looking for Tuple2[A,B]

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that Slick `.groupBy` requires a `.map` call with aggregating functions afterwards. You can find detailed information [here](https://scala-slick.org/doc/3.1.1/sql-to-slick.html#group-by).
So, try this:

```scala
.groupBy(_._1.idPsgFk)
  .map{ case (key, group) => (key, group.map(_._2).countDistinct)}
    .filter{ case (_, count) => count === 1}
      .map(_._1)
```

**P.S.**
I've also found "bad smells" in your code. You get pairs as a result of for-comrehension, but it looks like standard join would be more appropriate here (and more efficient), something like:

```scala
PassInTripTable.table.join(TripTable.table).on(_.tripNoFk === _.tripNo)
  .map{ case (pit, t) => ...}
```

And why would you use such condition:
`Case.If(t.townFrom <= t.townTo).Then(t.townFrom ++ t.townTo).Else(t.townFrom ++ t.townTo)`? Its branches are the same, so equals to `t.townFrom ++ t.townTo`.