# How to express this query in slick involving group by, having, count

Tags: scala, slick

Suppose I have a table defined like this in Slick 3.2.3:

```
class ATable(tag: Tag) extends Table[(Int, Option[Boolean])](tag, "a_table") {
  def someInt = column[Int]("some_int")
  def someBool = column[Option[Boolean]]("some_bool")
  def * = (someInt, someBool)
}
object ATable extends TableQuery(new ATable(_))
```

and a bit of data to go with it:

```
insert into a_table
values
(1, true),
(2, null),
(2, true),
(2, null),
(3, true),
(3, true),
(3, null);
```

Now I'd like to find those ints in the table where there's exactly one row where `some_bool` is not `null`. This is not difficult in SQL:

```
select some_int
from a_table
group by some_int
having count(some_bool) = 1;
```

This works just fine. So let's try it with Slick:

```
ATable
 .groupBy(_.someInt)
 .filter(_._2.map(_.someBool).countDefined === 1)
 .map(_._1)
```

And while this compiles, it will crash at runtime with the error message “`slick.SlickTreeException: Cannot convert node to SQL Comprehension`”. Is this a known limitation or a bug in slick? Or am I supposed to write my query in a different way?
It's of course possible to write this with a subquery, but I'd rather understand why the `groupBy` thing doesn't work…

Comment: Similar problem - https://stackoverflow.com/q/47303514/6609485

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Slick`-equivalence of your SQL should look something like the `query` in the following example:

```
val aTable: TableQuery[ATable] = TableQuery[ATable]

val setupAction: DBIO[Unit] = DBIO.seq(
  aTable.schema.create,
  aTable += (1, Some(true)),
  aTable += (2, None),
  aTable += (2, Some(true)),
  aTable += (2, None),
  aTable += (3, Some(true)),
  aTable += (3, Some(true)),
  aTable += (3, None)
)

val setupFuture: Future[Unit] = db.run(setupAction)

val f = setupFuture.flatMap{ _ =>
  val query =
    aTable.groupBy(_.someInt).
      map{ case (someInt, group) => (someInt, group.map(_.someBool).countDefined) }.
      filter(_._2 === 1).
      map(_._1)

  println("Generated SQL for query:\n" + query.result.statements)
  db.run(query.result.map(println))
}

// Generated SQL for query:
// List(select "some_int" from "a_table" group by "some_int" having count("some_bool") = 1)
// Vector(1, 2)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response, this does indeed work. It's weird, because  with collections `foo.map(a => (a, f(a))).filter(_._2).map(_._1)` is equivalent to `foo.filter(f)`, so I'm tempted to call this a bug. I also found another issue: if you change `group.map(_.someBool).countDefined` to `group.map(_.someBool).distinct.length` it breaks again. Unfortunately this is actually what I need in my real world use case :-(

Comment: @Matthias Berndt, unfortunately my own experience with Slick's `groupBy` has also not been all that positive – for example, it supports only a limited set of aggregate functions.  Replacing `countDefined` with `countDistinct` would work in your case, but you'll get a `deprecated` warning.  And apparently, neither `distinct.length` nor `distinctOn(_.someBool)` would work within `groupBy`.

Comment: I see, thanks! It's clearly a bug then, since the documentation states that .distinct.length is what you're supposed to do instead of .countDistinct. Even worse than that is that I also need the values in another column which I was planning to get using array_agg. But that also doesn't work, because slick-pg doesn't support using those with groupBy (slick-pg bug #289). So it's all very sad :-(. Anyway, thanks for you help!